# Flutter crop 2 rotated images

Tags: image, flutter, rotation, crop

I need to achieve this effect in Flutter:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14LGH.png)

Any Ideas on how to do it?
The Images should have their own separate widgets to be more flexible.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Solution for me:

```
return Center(
  child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
      child: SizedOverflowBox(
        size: Size(150, 150),
        child: Transform.rotate(
          angle: -math.pi / 4,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                kFlagPathUK,
                width: 220.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Image.asset(
                kFlagPathUSA,
                width: 220.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Which looks like this:

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnQDu.png)

Comment: check `ClipRect` and `Transform.rotate` widgets

Answer (score 1):

You can get the basic rotation an position with this code, and depending on you images you'll need to resize them and position them regarding the parent widget.

```
return ClipRRect(
  child: Container(
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    color: Colors.grey,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(-90, -100),
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: -math.pi / 4,
            child: Image.asset('flag1.png'),
          ),
        ),
        Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(90, 100),
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: -math.pi / 4,
            child: Container(
              width: 500,
              child: Image.asset('flag2.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much.
I tried a different approach using a column widget (see original post).